# How to display info of selected items?

Tags: yii2

I am new in Yii framework, so I don't have much idea in it.
My question is, I want to get details of the company which is selected in a search box.

[image]

Code in my frontend/companies.php

```
<?= Html::SubmitButton( 'Get info', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' =>'getinfo']) ?>
```

Here's my select2 widget code:-

```
$typeahead =  Select2::widget([
'id' => 'front_companies_select',
'name' => 'state_10',
'data' => $companyNameList,
'options' => [
'placeholder' => 'Select ...',
'sigle' => true
],
]);
```

My js code:-

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){
        var obj = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").val();
        console.log(obj);
     });
```

Comment: are you getting value in console ?

Comment: Yes, I get values on the console.

Comment: So what you need at there?, If you want to get company details then you have to make ajax call by passing company id

Comment: now if you want to save its value which was selected then just a make a hidden field and get its value in post and save it.

Comment: how to display data from console to gridview ?? @NaimMalek

Comment: You can rise another question as here is different scenario @Goli

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only company name you can try this.

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){ 
    var company_id = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").val(); 
    console.log(company_id); 
    var companyName = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").text(); 
    console.log(companyName); //here you can get company name
});
```

Or If you want to get whole company details then you have to call `ajax` like this.

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){ 
    var company_id = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").val(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"YOUR_URL/YOUR_FUNCTION_TO_GET_COMPANY_DETAILS",
        data: {company_id:company_id},
        dataType:'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
          console.log(data); //here you can get all the company details in object
        }
    });

});
```